# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'public' (T_PUBLIC)

Tags: php, getstream-io

public function is used inside a class called Client but it still throws error like this for every function in that class. Any solution to this? I am trying to test getstream for php. I am getting this error in client.php
I know this error occurs when class isn't declared while using public function but in this case the class has been declared and according to the documentation this should have worked without an error.

```
    <?php
    namespace GuzzleHttp;

    use GuzzleHttp\Cookie\CookieJar;
    use GuzzleHttp\Promise;
    use GuzzleHttp\Psr7;
    use Psr\Http\Message\UriInterface;
    use Psr\Http\Message\RequestInterface;
    use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface;

    /**
     * @method ResponseInterface get(string|UriInterface $uri, array $options = [])
     * @method ResponseInterface head(string|UriInterface $uri, array $options = [])
     * @method ResponseInterface put(string|UriInterface $uri, array $options = [])
     * @method ResponseInterface post(string|UriInterface $uri, array $options = [])
     * @method ResponseInterface patch(string|UriInterface $uri, array $options = [])
     * @method ResponseInterface delete(string|UriInterface $uri, array $options = [])
     * @method Promise\PromiseInterface getAsync(string|UriInterface $uri, array $options = [])
     * @method Promise\PromiseInterface headAsync(string|UriInterface $uri, array $options = [])
     * @method Promise\PromiseInterface putAsync(string|UriInterface $uri, array $options = [])
     * @method Promise\PromiseInterface postAsync(string|UriInterface $uri, array $options = [])
     * @method Promise\PromiseInterface patchAsync(string|UriInterface $uri, array $options = [])
     * @method Promise\PromiseInterface deleteAsync(string|UriInterface $uri, array $options = [])
     */
    class Client implements ClientInterface
    {
        /** @var array Default request options */
        private $config;

        /**
         * Clients accept an array of constructor parameters.
         *
         * Here's an example of creating a client using a base_uri and an array of
         * default request options to apply to each request:
         *
         *     $client = new Client([
         *         'base_uri'        => 'http://www.foo.com/1.0/',
         *         'timeout'         => 0,
         *         'allow_redirects' => false,
         *         'proxy'           => '192.168.16.1:10'
         *     ]);
         *
         * Client configuration settings include the following options:
         *
         * - handler: (callable) Function that transfers HTTP requests over the
         *   wire. The function is called with a Psr7\Http\Message\RequestInterface
         *   and array of transfer options, and must return a
         *   GuzzleHttp\Promise\PromiseInterface that is fulfilled with a
         *   Psr7\Http\Message\ResponseInterface on success. "handler" is a
         *   constructor only option that cannot be overridden in per/request
         *   options. If no handler is provided, a default handler will be created
         *   that enables all of the request options below by attaching all of the
         *   default middleware to the handler.
         * - base_uri: (string|UriInterface) Base URI of the client that is merged
         *   into relative URIs. Can be a string or instance of UriInterface.
         * - **: any request option
         *
         * @param array $config Client configuration settings.
         *
         * @see \GuzzleHttp\RequestOptions for a list of available request options.
         */
        //public function __construct(array $config = [])
          public function __construct(array $config = ['verify' => false]) {
        {
            if (!isset($config['handler'])) {
                $config['handler'] = HandlerStack::create();
            }

            // Convert the base_uri to a UriInterface
            if (isset($config['base_uri'])) {
                $config['base_uri'] = Psr7\uri_for($config['base_uri']);
            }

            $this->configureDefaults($config);
        }

        public function __call($method, $args)
        {
            if (count($args) < 1) {
                throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Magic request methods require a URI and optional options array');
            }

            $uri = $args[0];
            $opts = isset($args[1]) ? $args[1] : [];

            return substr($method, -5) === 'Async'
                ? $this->requestAsync(substr($method, 0, -5), $uri, $opts)
                : $this->request($method, $uri, $opts);
        }

        public function sendAsync(RequestInterface $request, array $options = [])
        {
            // Merge the base URI into the request URI if needed.
            $options = $this->prepareDefaults($options);

            return $this->transfer(
                $request->withUri($this->buildUri($request->getUri(), $options), $request->hasHeader('Host')),
                $options
            );
        }

        public function send(RequestInterface $request, array $options = [])
        {
            $options[RequestOptions::SYNCHRONOUS] = true;
            return $this->sendAsync($request, $options)->wait();
        }

        public function requestAsync($method, $uri = '', array $options = [])
        {
            $options = $this->prepareDefaults($options);
            // Remove request modifying parameter because it can be done up-front.
            $headers = isset($options['headers']) ? $options['headers'] : [];
            $body = isset($options['body']) ? $options['body'] : null;
            $version = isset($options['version']) ? $options['version'] : '1.1';
            // Merge the URI into the base URI.
            $uri = $this->buildUri($uri, $options);
            if (is_array($body)) {
                $this->invalidBody();
            }
            $request = new Psr7\Request($method, $uri, $headers, $body, $version);
            // Remove the option so that they are not doubly-applied.
            unset($options['headers'], $options['body'], $options['version']);

            return $this->transfer($request, $options);
        }

        public function request($method, $uri = '', array $options = [])
        {
            $options[RequestOptions::SYNCHRONOUS] = true;
            return $this->requestAsync($method, $uri, $options)->wait();
        }

        public function getConfig($option = null)
        {
            return $option === null
                ? $this->config
                : (isset($this->config[$option]) ? $this->config[$option] : null);
        }

        private function buildUri($uri, array $config)
        {
            // for BC we accept null which would otherwise fail in uri_for
            $uri = Psr7\uri_for($uri === null ? '' : $uri);

            if (isset($config['base_uri'])) {
                $uri = Psr7\UriResolver::resolve(Psr7\uri_for($config['base_uri']), $uri);
            }

            return $uri->getScheme() === '' && $uri->getHost() !== '' ? $uri->withScheme('http') : $uri;
        }

        /**
         * Configures the default options for a client.
         *
         * @param array $config
         */
        private function configureDefaults(array $config)
        {
            $defaults = [
                'allow_redirects' => RedirectMiddleware::$defaultSettings,
                'http_errors'     => true,
                'decode_content'  => true,
                'verify'          => true,
                'cookies'         => false
            ];

            // Use the standard Linux HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY if set.

            // We can only trust the HTTP_PROXY environment variable in a CLI
            // process due to the fact that PHP has no reliable mechanism to
            // get environment variables that start with "HTTP_".
            if (php_sapi_name() == 'cli' && getenv('HTTP_PROXY')) {
                $defaults['proxy']['http'] = getenv('HTTP_PROXY');
            }

            if ($proxy = getenv('HTTPS_PROXY')) {
                $defaults['proxy']['https'] = $proxy;
            }

            if ($noProxy = getenv('NO_PROXY')) {
                $cleanedNoProxy = str_replace(' ', '', $noProxy);
                $defaults['proxy']['no'] = explode(',', $cleanedNoProxy);
            }

            $this->config = $config + $defaults;

            if (!empty($config['cookies']) && $config['cookies'] === true) {
                $this->config['cookies'] = new CookieJar();
            }

            // Add the default user-agent header.
            if (!isset($this->config['headers'])) {
                $this->config['headers'] = ['User-Agent' => default_user_agent()];
            } else {
                // Add the User-Agent header if one was not already set.
                foreach (array_keys($this->config['headers']) as $name) {
                    if (strtolower($name) === 'user-agent') {
                        return;
                    }
                }
                $this->config['headers']['User-Agent'] = default_user_agent();
            }
        }

        /**
         * Merges default options into the array.
         *
         * @param array $options Options to modify by reference
         *
         * @return array
         */
        private function prepareDefaults($options)
        {
            $defaults = $this->config;

            if (!empty($defaults['headers'])) {
                // Default headers are only added if they are not present.
                $defaults['_conditional'] = $defaults['headers'];
                unset($defaults['headers']);
            }

            // Special handling for headers is required as they are added as
            // conditional headers and as headers passed to a request ctor.
            if (array_key_exists('headers', $options)) {
                // Allows default headers to be unset.
                if ($options['headers'] === null) {
                    $defaults['_conditional'] = null;
                    unset($options['headers']);
                } elseif (!is_array($options['headers'])) {
                    throw new \InvalidArgumentException('headers must be an array');
                }
            }

            // Shallow merge defaults underneath options.
            $result = $options + $defaults;

            // Remove null values.
            foreach ($result as $k => $v) {
                if ($v === null) {
                    unset($result[$k]);
                }
            }

            return $result;
        }

        /**
         * Transfers the given request and applies request options.
         *
         * The URI of the request is not modified and the request options are used
         * as-is without merging in default options.
         *
         * @param RequestInterface $request
         * @param array            $options
         *
         * @return Promise\PromiseInterface
         */
        private function transfer(RequestInterface $request, array $options)
        {
            // save_to -> sink
            if (isset($options['save_to'])) {
                $options['sink'] = $options['save_to'];
                unset($options['save_to']);
            }

            // exceptions -> http_errors
            if (isset($options['exceptions'])) {
                $options['http_errors'] = $options['exceptions'];
                unset($options['exceptions']);
            }

            $request = $this->applyOptions($request, $options);
            $handler = $options['handler'];

            try {
                return Promise\promise_for($handler($request, $options));
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                return Promise\rejection_for($e);
            }
        }

        /**
         * Applies the array of request options to a request.
         *
         * @param RequestInterface $request
         * @param array            $options
         *
         * @return RequestInterface
         */
        private function applyOptions(RequestInterface $request, array &$options)
        {
            $modify = [];

            if (isset($options['form_params'])) {
                if (isset($options['multipart'])) {
                    throw new \InvalidArgumentException('You cannot use '
                        . 'form_params and multipart at the same time. Use the '
                        . 'form_params option if you want to send application/'
                        . 'x-www-form-urlencoded requests, and the multipart '
                        . 'option to send multipart/form-data requests.');
                }
                $options['body'] = http_build_query($options['form_params'], '', '&');
                unset($options['form_params']);
                $options['_conditional']['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
            }

            if (isset($options['multipart'])) {
                $options['body'] = new Psr7\MultipartStream($options['multipart']);
                unset($options['multipart']);
            }

            if (isset($options['json'])) {
                $options['body'] = \GuzzleHttp\json_encode($options['json']);
                unset($options['json']);
                $options['_conditional']['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';
            }

            if (!empty($options['decode_content'])
                && $options['decode_content'] !== true
            ) {
                $modify['set_headers']['Accept-Encoding'] = $options['decode_content'];
            }

            if (isset($options['headers'])) {
                if (isset($modify['set_headers'])) {
                    $modify['set_headers'] = $options['headers'] + $modify['set_headers'];
                } else {
                    $modify['set_headers'] = $options['headers'];
                }
                unset($options['headers']);
            }

            if (isset($options['body'])) {
                if (is_array($options['body'])) {
                    $this->invalidBody();
                }
                $modify['body'] = Psr7\stream_for($options['body']);
                unset($options['body']);
            }

            if (!empty($options['auth']) && is_array($options['auth'])) {
                $value = $options['auth'];
                $type = isset($value[2]) ? strtolower($value[2]) : 'basic';
                switch ($type) {
                    case 'basic':
                        $modify['set_headers']['Authorization'] = 'Basic '
                            . base64_encode("$value[0]:$value[1]");
                        break;
                    case 'digest':
                        // @todo: Do not rely on curl
                        $options['curl'][CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH] = CURLAUTH_DIGEST;
                        $options['curl'][CURLOPT_USERPWD] = "$value[0]:$value[1]";
                        break;
                }
            }

            if (isset($options['query'])) {
                $value = $options['query'];
                if (is_array($value)) {
                    $value = http_build_query($value, null, '&', PHP_QUERY_RFC3986);
                }
                if (!is_string($value)) {
                    throw new \InvalidArgumentException('query must be a string or array');
                }
                $modify['query'] = $value;
                unset($options['query']);
            }

            // Ensure that sink is not an invalid value.
            if (isset($options['sink'])) {
                // TODO: Add more sink validation?
                if (is_bool($options['sink'])) {
                    throw new \InvalidArgumentException('sink must not be a boolean');
                }
            }

            $request = Psr7\modify_request($request, $modify);
            if ($request->getBody() instanceof Psr7\MultipartStream) {
                // Use a multipart/form-data POST if a Content-Type is not set.
                $options['_conditional']['Content-Type'] = 'multipart/form-data; boundary='
                    . $request->getBody()->getBoundary();
            }

            // Merge in conditional headers if they are not present.
            if (isset($options['_conditional'])) {
                // Build up the changes so it's in a single clone of the message.
                $modify = [];
                foreach ($options['_conditional'] as $k => $v) {
                    if (!$request->hasHeader($k)) {
                        $modify['set_headers'][$k] = $v;
                    }
                }
                $request = Psr7\modify_request($request, $modify);
                // Don't pass this internal value along to middleware/handlers.
                unset($options['_conditional']);
            }

            return $request;
        }

        private function invalidBody()
        {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Passing in the "body" request '
                . 'option as an array to send a POST request has been deprecated. '
                . 'Please use the "form_params" request option to send a '
                . 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded request, or a the "multipart" '
                . 'request option to send a multipart/form-data request.');
        }
    }
```

Comment: Use proper indentation, and you'll notice you're missing a brace on your construct function

Comment: How about using an tool like `NetBeans` for developing.

Comment: And if this part of code is from `getstream-io` or `GuzzleHttp` please tell them that they given broken code to people.

Comment: it's from GuzzleHttp, and it's not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

public function __construct(array $config = ['verify' => false]) {
        { // <-- duplicated brace here